# mix and matching hats and hairstyles

Tags: 3d, blender, godot

I making a character creation scene, I learned how armors work and how to cut the players in pieces to mix and match everything.... but matching hair styles with hats is incredibly tedious... since every gender and race has at least 12 hair styles and females have can have up to 38 hair styles...

am I like supposed to take every single hair style and making a different version for every single hat/helmet to fit with it? or are the better systems?

From the mmos I have played, I noticed that no one affronted this problem. most big game development studios just ignore this problem.... in most MMOS if you wear a hat it either clips horribly through the hair or you just can't wear headgear at all.... and in other games like lineage or tera, every hat as a default hair style so say if you picked hairstyle 1 in character creation then in game find a hat and wear it, your hair will switch to maybe hairstyle 12... like you maybe choose a bald character but then wear a pirate hat and suddently have long hair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes work. Are you "supposed" to do it...? Well, no. As you have pointed out many games avoid the problem. It could have made sense to them to start with the minimum viable version of the feature, and only expand on if if they find demand from the players.

Think about it form the point of view of those studios. They could pay artists to do this tedious work, right? It could be hard to financially justify it without a direct return on investment (i.e. selling them on micro-transactions). But if they find out in practice that there is demand, there might be a price players are willing to pay.

---

Now, you don't have to do all or nothing.

You can use bone attachments for the hats, so you are not making every combinations. That leaves you at risk of clipping... To address that, you could ban the use of hats on hairstyles that would result in clipping.

Furthermore, establish guidelines to make hairstyles and hats such that they avoid clipping. Then you can offer a selection of hairstyles that work with hats, and others that don't (which would be the extravagant ones, since they are not constrained by the guidelines to avoid clipping).

So no hat would make hair appear, players would have more than one option for hairstyle using hats, and no hat would cause clipping, and extravagant hairstyles still exist.

---

And why would a hairstyle not work with hats? Well, that is what happens in reality... Or, if you prefer, think that adding a hat to the hairstyle modifies it.

Which would translate to having a version of the hairstyle that works with hats, and another that does not. And you might even automatically switch between them.

Furthermore, if the versions of the hairstyles that work with hats are only used when the player has a hat. Then creating them could be as simple as removing the parts of the geometry that could cause clipping.